# In Mimemessage how to set Rawinputstream in Content

Tags: jakarta-mail

I'm having content which encoded in base 64 format already. I want to set content in Mimemessage in object as if the content is in base64 format. Is there any method available for this? Please provide solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/PreencodedMimeBodyPart.html